# In Chrome Native messaging: how long is the native app instance object lifetime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging, nativeapplication

Does a native application that talks to a Chrome extension is alive for ever? I mean should it be present e.g. before a postback happens? I could not find any configuration for that to add in the manifest file.

I have a page, there are some objects on the page. After clicking an object and sending/receving one message with the Native app, then it no longer works for the rest of objects.

**My exact question**: How long is the native app instance object lifetime? Should that object response e.g. forever? Or do I need a loop e.g. to read messages from stdin if this is a continuous communication?

**Here is my background script:**

```
var host_name = "files.mffta.java.nativeapp";
var port = null;
initPort();
function initPort() {
    console.log( 'Connecting to native host: ' + host_name );
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative( host_name );
    port.onMessage.addListener( onNativeMessage );
    port.onDisconnect.addListener( onDisconnected );
}

// Listen for messages that come from the content script.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function( messageData, sender, sendResponse ) {
    if( messageData ) {
        sendNativeMessage(messageData);
        sendResponse( { res: 'done!' } );
    }
  } );

// Sending a message to the port.
function sendNativeMessage(messageData) {
    if( port == null )
        initPort();
    console.log( 'Sending message to native app: ' + JSON.stringify( messageData ) );
    port.postMessage( messageData );
    console.log( 'Sent message to native app.' );
}

// Receiving a message back from the Native Client API.
function onNativeMessage( message ) {
    console.log( 'recieved message from native app: ' + JSON.stringify( message ) );

    alert( "messaged received from Native: " + JSON.stringify( message ) );
    //sending a message to Content Script to call a function
    if( message.methodName && message.methodName != "" ) {
        chrome.tabs.query( { active: true, currentWindow: true }, function( tabs ) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabs[0].id, message, function( response ) {
                // Call native again to return JavaScript callback function results
                alert ("calc res received by extension : " + response);
                sendNativeMessage({ type: "JSCallbackRes", callbackRes: response });
            } );
        } );
    }
}

// Disconnecting the port.
function onDisconnected() {
    console.log( "ERROR: " + JSON.stringify( chrome.runtime.lastError ) );
    console.log( 'disconnected from native app.' );
    port = null;
}
```

**My extension manifest:**

```
{
  "name": "Files.ChromeExt.Operarations",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension calls a Native API which that API calls some x-Files related operations.",
  "icons": {
    "128": "x-files_icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging", "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{"matches": ["http://localhost/*","https://localhost/*"], 
    "js": ["contentscripts/page.js"]}]
}
```

**Java program:** [as has been asked in the comments]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Applet {

    public Applet(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            readMessage();
            sendMessage("{\"msg\" : \"hello\"}");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String readMessage() {
        String msg = "";
        try {
            int c, t = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                t += Math.pow(256.0f, i) * System.in.read();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                c = System.in.read();
                msg += (char) c;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error in reading message from JS");
        }
        return msg;
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String msgdata) {
        try {
            int dataLength = msgdata.length();
            System.out.write((byte) (dataLength & 0xFF));
            System.out.write((byte) ((dataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
            System.out.write((byte) ((dataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
            System.out.write((byte) ((dataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));

            // Writing the message itself
            System.out.write(msgdata.getBytes());
            System.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error in sending message to JS");
        }
    }
}
```

By inspecting the chrome log I can see these messages:

- *Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 1936028240 bytes long.*
- *{"message":"Error when communicating with the native messaging host."}", source: chrome-extension://XXX*

I am testing these on a Win 8.0 machine 64 bit.

**Update:**
I am now convinced that the host is alive forever if connectNative is called and the port is not stopped by an error. So, the root cause of the error messages above must be something else than port lifetime. I mean some error in my communication is forcibly stopping the port.

I highly appreciate any comments you can give.

Comment: I think it is quite clear from the error in the log that the length of the message is somehow getting completely mangled. That is an error in communication, and causes the port to be closed.

Comment: Then who is mangling that as my whole program is what you can see here. No "System.out", no other intermediate function to corrupt the message. I expect to see 'recieved message from native app: ' in my log, but the communication gets broken and no such a message in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using [`chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage), the native app will be around right after receiving and before sending the message. Since reception of the message is asynchronous, you cannot assume that the app is still alive when the callback of `sendNativeMessage` is called.

If you want to ensure that the native app stays around longer, use [`chrome.runtime.connectNative`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connectNative). This creates a port, and the native app will be alive until it exits or until the extension calls `disconnect()` on the port. If your app unexpectedly terminates early, then you have most likely made an error in the implementation of the native messaging protocol.

For the exact format of the native messaging protocol, take a look at the documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol

---

As for your edit, the error message is quite clear: The length is invalid. The length is supposed to be in the system's **native byte order** (which could be [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) or [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian)). When you get the following arror message with an excessive offset difference, then there are two possibilities:

1. The byte order of the integer is incorrect, or
2. Your output contains some unexpected characters, which causes the bytes to be shifted and resulted in bytes being at the incorrect location.

To know which case you're in, view the number as a hexadecimal number. If there are many trailing zeroes, then that shows that the byte order is incorrect. For example, if your message has a length of 59, then the hexadecimal value is `3b`. If the endianness is incorrect, then the following message is displayed:

> Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 989855744 bytes long.

1493172224 is `3b 00 00 00` in hexadecimal notation, and you can observe that the `3b` is there, but at the wrong end (in other words, the byte order is reversed). The solution to this problem for your system is to edit your code to print the bytes in the reverse order.

If the hexadecimal view of the number does not look remotely close to your number, then odds are that the message length is incorrect. Recall that stdio is used for communication, so if you output anything else (e.g. errors) to stdout (`System.out`) instead of stderr (`System.err`), then the protocol is violated and your app will be terminated.

```java
        System.err.println(ex.getStackTrace());                     // <-- OK
        System.out.println("[ error -> " + ex.getMessage() + " ]"); // <-- BAD
```

On Windows, also check whether you've [set the mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) for stdout (and stdin) to O_BINARY. Otherwise Windows will insert an extra byte before `0A` (`0D 0A`), which causes all bytes to shift and the number to be incorrect. [The Java Runtime already enables binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320329/how-to-set-stdin-mode-to-binary-in-java/31538986#31538986), so for your case it's not relevant.

Comment: One thing I did not test: if the port object is garbage-collected, does that kill the process?

Comment: @Xan Good question, I don't know the answer off-hand. I know that the port is disconnected & destroyed when the response callback is not called upon `onMessage` (despite `return true;`), but I don't know for sure what happens to the port when the creator discards the port. It will probably stick around, but you have to test that or dig in the source code to know for sure.

Comment: Um, what? _"port is disconnected & destroyed when the response callback is not called upon onMessage"_ - that sounds strange - you have to answer with a message to every incoming message?

Comment: @Xan Usually not, my previous comment refers to the case when the extension is the receiver of the port (this is not relevant for native messaging, only extension / externally_connectable messaging). The port automatically closes itself after dispatching `onMessage`, unless `return true;` is used (as you know). If the extension forgets to call the response callback, Chrome will still destroy the received port during garbage collection of the response callback, which will ultimately trigger the callback of the sender (in a content script or (extension) page).

Comment: Ah, right. That was confusing since the question is about Native Messaging, which can only have `onMessage` on the port object (and that does not behave this way).

Comment: @Xan Sorry for the confusion. I just offered the example because it shows that there exist GC "magic" to handle the lifetime of the ports. Whether similar "magic" exists for created ports remains to be seen. Here is the source code if you're interested in digging: https://cs.chromium.org/file%3Aextensions/renderer/resources/messaging.js

Comment: Rob, thanks for the answer. I have yet another question which is somewhat related to this one. I think the constructor of my Native app class is not called. It is a Java program with a static main method, my class is not static though. I wonder how an instance of this host is get initialized?

Comment: @RezaAhmadi In a Java program, you typically initialize your class in the main class like `public class Main { Main() { /*your stuff*/} public static void main(String[] args) { new Main(); }}`. If this advice doesn't help, please show the relevant part of your program's source code.

Comment: @RobW, I added some code there; my extension background.js and manifest. My problem at the moment is that I can read/send first messages with my host, but the second message to my extension is not received. I appreciate any comment on that.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi Also show the relevant part of your Java program.

Comment: @RobW: I added Java program part, related parts plus some log reports. I am really confused why there is those log lines. One thing that would be its reason is 'set mode' which I could not change it to Binary so far. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: @RobW Deleted my answer, yours is superior.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks for your answer and all comments. Your answer was informative for me in some aspects. But, it did not solve the problem. Still the log file says: 
"Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 973078528 bytes long". This time, the sending message seems to be smaller in bytes, though. Btw, how do you know which order of bytes I need to choose?
Also still there is that message: "Error when communicating with the native messaging host".  
Any more comments? Thanks very much.
Btw, I also checked all the side notes you had provided.

Comment: @RobW: I am also a bit suspicious about stdin mode, which I have asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320329/how-to-set-stdin-mode-to-binary-in-java
I mean, I think I need to change the mode to BINARY.

Comment: @RobW: I am now convinced that set mode is not needed. Any more thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @RobW: Yes and I tried it. Please have a look at my previous three comments. Thanks.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi Oh, I overlooked that comment. Let's clean up the comments by deleting all comments starting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515791/in-chrome-native-messaging-how-long-is-the-native-app-instance-object-lifetime/31517513?noredirect=1#comment51043649_31517513. I'll take a look at your previous reply.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi The code in your question doesn't compile at all. Please reduce the code to a minimum that compiles *and* demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RobW You need a lib along with another class, shall I send a zip file (the working program) to rob@robwu.nl? Or I can add references for that lib and add the class.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi I'm not thrilled to dig through hundred lines of code... Create a new file, put your existing code over there, then trim all code that is not necessary for the communication part. After doing that, you will have a reasonably small file that ought to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi By the way, try reverting to your original way of counting bytes. The error from Chrome complains about a length of 0x3A000000, which looks like an incorrect byte order. Your original error was probably caused by writing non-message data to stdout for debugging, as the reported number doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83893/discussion-between-reza-ahmadi-and-rob-w).

Comment: @RobW: How about Windows, have you tried? I am testing using Win 8.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi Eh, I meant to say that I've successfully tested the code on Linux and Windows 7 (not Mac).

Comment: @RezaAhmadi Please show the error that you get with the **code from the question**. While the code is now properly reduced to a minimal example (good job!), the error message seems unchanged (which is extremely unlikely).

Comment: @RobW: I accepted the answer, but please remove that "message length writing" part as it may mislead some others. The solution helped me to get rid of some mangling "system.out.println"s in my code.